# If $p,q$ are prime and $p,q$ is not eqaul to $2$ then prove that $[\frac{p^q+q^p}{pq}]$ is even , where [x] denotes the greatest integer function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p,q$ are prime and $p,q$ is not eqaul to $2$ then prove that $[\frac{p^q+q^p}{pq}]$ is even , where [x] denotes the greatest integer function.

We know that $p^q+q^p\equiv p+q(mod pq)$ ...bu does that help here? I am getting how to do it...Also, $p^q+q^p$ is even but $p,q$ is not so, $pq$ is odd...But how to prove $[\frac{p^q+q^p}{pq}]$ is even .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $p^q + q^p \equiv (p + q)\pmod{pq}$ then $p^q + q^p - p - q = pq u$ for some integer $u$. Both $p$ and $q$ are odd, so $p^q + q^p - p - q$ is even. Thus $pq u$ is even. Since $pq$ is odd, $u$ must be even. Now $$\left\lfloor \frac{p^q + q^p}{pq}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{p+q}{pq}\right\rfloor + u$$ and $$0 < \frac{p+q}{pq} = \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{p} < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$$ Hence $\lfloor \frac{p+q}{pq}\rfloor = 0$ and $$\left\lfloor \frac{p^q + q^p}{pq}\right\rfloor = u$$ which is even.

Comment: Thanks! But how do u draw the conclusion that $[\frac{p^q+q^p}{p+q}]=[\frac{p+q}{pq}]=u$?...I am not quite getting it...

Comment: But how do u write $p+q$ as $pq$ ...I mean in the expression where u wrote $\frac{p+q+pqu}{p+q}=\frac{p+q}{pq}+u$...how did u draw this conclusion..i am not getting it...

Comment: @Franklin those were typos, sorry. I have made corrections.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now....